# Android java Two Listners for edittext

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-edittext

can you have two listeners at the same time.

I have two EditText which are defined as follows

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextnum"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:inputType="number">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextnum2"
       android:layout_width="0sp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/back"
       android:ems="10"
       android:imeOptions="actionDone"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="30dp">
```

When I get focus any either one it brings up a soft numeric keypad so that I can enter a number and then press done. the following code is run on pressing done while focused on EditTexnum 2

```
//Listner and result in MainActivity.java
db = new DBAdapter(this);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnum2);
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    EditText mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextnum2);
                    if(mEdit.length()==0){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Fault Reference Number Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        db.open();  
                        Cursor c = db.getAsset2(mEdit.getText());
                        if (c.moveToFirst())        
                            DisplayContact(c);
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Fault Reference found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }                        
                        db.close();
```

This works perfect for editTextnum2 but editTextnum doesnt do anything because there isnt a listener

i have tried copying the text and changing the listener but it kepps throwing erros

basically hat I am doing is they are search boxes that search an sqlite database but they search on two different columns

Any idea how I do this?

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnum2);
```

You are binding `editText` to `R.id.editTextnum2`

Make sure for other text box you bind it as

```
another_editText_var = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnum);
```

and register listener as    `another_editText_var.setOnEditorActionListener(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Not...Entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but setting two listeners is dependant on what kind of listener it is.  An edittext can have multiple TextWatcher listeners. like so

```
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnum);

    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Both listeners will be invoked.